# How can I append text fetched from ajax to my html code in a specific format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have the following html code:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-alerts">
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <div>
                <i class="fa fa-comment fa-fw"></i> New Comment

                <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
</ul>
```

and in my jquery code I'm fetching data from ajax in a specific form:

```
[{
    "Content": "lorem Ipsum",
    "Date": "2015-10-21 19:00:00"
}, {
    "Content": "lorem Ipsum",
    "Date": "2015-10-21 19:00:00"
}, {
    "Content": "lorem Ipsum",
    "Date": "2015-10-21 19:00:00"
},
etc.]
```

and I fetch it as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    url: './fetchData.php',
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        mail: mail
    },
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(ans) {    
        var data = JSON.parse(ans);

        $.each(data, function(i, v) {
            console.log(v.Date);
            console.log(v.Content);

        });
    });
    .
    .
    .
});
```

Now, instead of writing it on the console, I would like to create the several `<li>` nodes inside `<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-alerts">` with the fetched content inside. How can I do that?

Comment: Like `$("<li>" + v.Date + "</li>")` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `append` (bottom) / `prepend` (top) on `$('ul.dropdown-alerts')` to add li with response data as following:

```
$.each(data, function(i, v) {
    $('ul.dropdown-alerts').append('<li><a href="#"><div><i class="fa fa-comment fa-fw"></i>' + v.Content + '<span class="pull-right text-muted small">' + v.Date + '</span></div></a></li>');

    /* if you want to append divider li as well */
    $('ul.dropdown-alerts').append('<li class="divider"></li>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
$.each(data, function(i, v) {
var result = $('<li><a href="#"><div><i class="fa fa-comment fa-fw"></i>' + v.Content + '<span class="pull-right text-muted small">' + v.Date + '</span></div></a></li>');
$('div').html(result);    
        });
```